# Why is this producing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm not sure why the following is producing a segmentation fault. I've defined a structure and I'm trying to store a value to it.

```
typedef struct {
    int sourceid;
    int destid;
} TEST_STRUCT;

void  main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
    TEST_STRUCT *test;
    test->sourceid = 5;
}
```

Comment: But `test` is not set - it is pointing to some random location in memory.

Comment: No time for a proper answer but in essence you need to allocate memory space. You just declared a pointer variable but you don’t know where it is pointing to..,

Comment: Declaring a pointer to a type does not allocate memory.

Answer (score 2):

You declare a pointer to the type. You need to allocate memory for the pointer to point to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int sourceid;
    int destid;
} TEST_STRUCT;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    TEST_STRUCT *test;
    test = malloc(sizeof(TEST_STRUCT));
    if (test) {
        test->sourceid = 5;
        free(test);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could declare the variable on the stack:

```
typedef struct {
    int sourceid;
    int destid;
} TEST_STRUCT;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    TEST_STRUCT test;
    test.sourceid = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

test pointer is not pointing to any address(pointing some garbage) so it is hitting segV

```
 TEST_STRUCT *test;
```

it is good practice to initialize `NULL` and before dereference it, check `if (test != NULL) {}`
then only dereference.

to solve this, first `you need to create variable of TEST_STRUCT and assign address of it` to test pointer or allocate memory using malloc/calloc and then try this

Comment: When formatting, you can enclose inline code in backticks, e.g. `\`...\`` to format as code (fixed font with off-color background) An example of *"you need to create variable of TEST_STRUCT and assign address of it to test"* would also be nice.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for educating,  I will improve on it :-)

Comment: Yep, I know, just trying to help you along. Good luck on S.O. and with your coding.